# How to make new database keywords in Katalon Studio and use them

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

How to make custom scripts and use them?

I already made a database connection script and I'm using it in Test Case but now I don't want to use select statements.

I made an SQLHandler where I connect to DB and I want to make another to perform select action.

The script I provided I use in my test case and want to hide it from test case and use something like my SQLHandler:

```
SQLHandler sql = new SQLHandler()

List<GroovyRowResult> res = sql.getSelectResults('SELECT COUNT(*) as calls FROM test WHERE canc IS NOT NULL AND cncat IS NULL')

int countFromDb = res.get(0).get('Calls')
println("No. of rows in Database is(are):" + res.get(0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create custom keyword and hide the select statement there. An example of custom keyword looks like:

```
class sample {

@Keyword
def getResource() {
    SQLHandler sql = new SQLHandler()
    List<GroovyRowResult> res = sql.getSelectResults('SELECT COUNT(*) as calls FROM test WHERE canc IS NOT NULL AND cncat IS NULL')
    int countFromDb = res.get(0).get('Calls')
    println("No. of rows in Database is(are):" + res.get(0))

    return res.get(0))
}
```

More information could be found at https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/videos/custom_keywords_and_method_call_statements.html

Comment: Hey Tony, I made so as you did, but I dont know how to import or use it in my Test Case. I tried too many things but nothing works.

Comment: Tony that helped me I added a custom keyword and used it. Now the Select statement works. But now i have different problem if you see in script there is countFromDb and I want to use it in if statement also in test case, but don't know how to perform that action

Comment: The videos in the link I provided (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=140&v=2zc2x1BcRMo) has detail instruction on how to call custom keyword from test case.

Comment: I've watched it but I already did that action. I can call class with this CustomKeywords.'db_connection.sample.getResource'(), but I need then only one object from class countFromDB to perform actions: if (countFromDb != rows_count) and i can't get countFromDb value

Comment: Examples:

def row_cnt = CustomKeywords.'db_connection.sample.getResource'()
def cnt = 0
if (row_cnt != cnt) {do something}